# YouTube streaming

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

In YouTube streaming API we can create a broadcast and stream, but how do I actually start streaming?

I mean, when we create a broadcast with the browser, we have to click the "preview button" first. And when YouTube receives streaming content, then we can click on the "broadcast button".

What is the equivalent API call for this? Pointing to either Java, Python, or PHP API is fine for me, thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about how to handle the transition state? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition

Comment: @PatrickLC I think so. I'm asking it for someone else and they haven't tried it but it looks correct. I would offer you the bounty if you post, otherwise I'll give it to Pepijn. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition) for live broadcast transition states:

> Changes the status of a YouTube live broadcast and initiates any
>   processes associated with the new status. For example, when you
>   transition a broadcast's status to testing, YouTube starts to transmit
>   video to that broadcast's monitor stream. Before calling this method,
>   you should confirm that the value of the status.streamStatus property
>   for the stream bound to your broadcast is active.

The broadcastStatus parameter identifies the state to which the broadcast is changing. Note that to transition a broadcast to either the testing or live state, the status.streamStatus must be active for the stream that the broadcast is bound to.

Acceptable values for the `broadcastStatus` parameter are:

- complete – The broadcast is over. YouTube stops transmitting video.
- live – The broadcast is visible to its audience. YouTube transmits
  video to the broadcast's monitor stream and its broadcast stream.
- testing – Start testing the broadcast. YouTube transmits video to the
  broadcast's monitor stream. Note that you can only transition a
  broadcast to the testing state if its
  contentDetails.monitorStream.enableMonitorStream property is set to
  true.

Answer (score 1):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition
```

When setting broadcastStatus to live you're going live. When setting it to testing YouTube only transmits video to the broadcast's monitor stream.

More info here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition